# Can I run gigabyte gforce gtx750ti 4GB with my 420W power supply?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

I am looking to buy the gigabyte geforce gtx750ti 4GB graphics card.
The power supply system requirement says that I need a 400W minimum and my power supply has 420W so I guess that I have enough or am I wrong?
can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Yes definately, also I quickly checked the specs (Minimum **System** Power Requirement) on the [nvidia page](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-750-ti/specifications) and it says the card needs 300W only.

If you think about overclocking this [tool here](http://outervision.com/power-supply-calculator) might become handy.

Comment: I checked this page http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5572#kf  and it says 400W. do you think I can run this?

Comment: Yes, as it is the Minimum System Power Req. and you meet that. Of course it depends on other power heavy components your computer might have, but as I don't have this information I assume there is nothing special attached to your machine.

Comment: Also in the worst case it won't work or you experience instabilities, so you can still replace the PSU later in case that would happen.

Comment: but if I plug it in and it won't work, will it damage my other hardware?

Comment: this might be helpfull: I have a AMD FX 3,6Ghz quadcore processor, 8GB ddr3 ram memory, 2 x 500gb harddrive and a 240GB SSD also i have 2 fans attached to my case

Comment: @randomguy No, this will not damage the hardware, not even the PSU itself, as they normally have a shortcut or overload protection built-in.